# SQL coalesce(): what type does the combined column have?

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

Lets say I use `coalesce()` to combine two columns into one in select and subsequently a view constructed around such select.

Tables:

```
values_int
id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY
value INTEGER(11)

values_varchar
id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY
value VARCHAR(255)

vals
id INTEGER(11) PRIMARY KEY
value INTEGER(11) //foreign key to both values_int and values_varchar
```

The primary keys between `values_int` and `values_varchar` are unique and that allows me to do:

```
SELECT vals.id, coalesce(values_int.value, values_varchar.value) AS value
FROM vals
JOIN values_int ON values_int.id = vals.value
JOIN values_varchar ON values_varchar.id = vals.value
```

This produces nice assembled view with ID column and combined value column that contains actual values from two other tables combined into single column.

- What type does this combined column have?
- When turned into view and then queried with a WHERE clause using this combined "value" column, how is that actually handled type-wise? I.e. `WHERE value > 10`

Som rambling thoughts in the need (most likely wrong):
The reason I am asking this is that the alternative to this design have all three tables merged into one with INT values in one column and VARCHAR in the other. That would of course produce a lots of NULL values in both columns but saved me the JOINs. For some reason I do not like that solution because it would require additional type checking to choose the right column and deal with the NULL values but maybe this presented design would require the same too (if the resulting column is actually VARCHAR). I would hope that it actually passes the WHERE clause down the view to the source (so that the column does NOT have a type per se) but I am likely wrong about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query should be explicit to be clear, In this case mysql is using varchar.

I would write this query like this to be clear

```
coalesce(values_int.value,cast(values_varchar.value as integer), 0)
```

or

```
coalesce(cast(values_int.value as varchar(20)),values_varchar.value,'0')
```

you should put in that last value unless you want the column to be null if both columns are null.

Comment: Hm you are right in that I should specify the type myself of course. Although Daniel Boncioaga is apparently correct about the type that is automatically chosen - highest that fits all columns so in this case it is indeed VARCHAR (otherwise I could not see the "correct" result with both strings and integers).

Comment: You probably want varchar since all integers can be varchars but not all varchars can be integers.  Still just explicit cast it to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable.

So in your case the type will be `VARCHAR(255)`

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say I use coalesce() to combine two columns into one

NO, that's not the use of `COALESCE` function. It's used for choosing a provided default value if the column value is null. So in your case, if `values_int.value IS NULL` then it will select the value in `values_varchar.value`

```
coalesce(values_int.value, values_varchar.value) AS value
```

If you want to combine the data then use concatenation operator (OR) `CONCAT()` function rather like

```
concat(values_int.value, values_varchar.value) AS value
```

Comment: I understand the difference and the coalesce is used on purpose. The vals.value column is foreign key to BOTH the other two tables and thus when the value is present in one it is never present in the other. Hence the coalesce which gets me rid off the other value (that is always NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Verify it yourself.  An easy way to check in MySQL is to DESCRIBE a VIEW you create to capture your dynamic column:

```
mysql> CREATE VIEW v AS
    -> SELECT vals.id, coalesce(values_int.value, values_varchar.value) AS value
    -> FROM vals
    -> JOIN values_int ON values_int.id = vals.value
    -> JOIN values_varchar ON values_varchar.id = vals.value;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now `DESCRIBE v` will show you what's what.  Note that under MySQL 5.1, I see the column as `varbinary(255)`, but under 5.5 I see `varchar(255)`.